# Calculating Taylor series of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm going through a past exam paper and found a question I can't do.

The question is to write down the Taylor expansion of $\frac{z^2}{z-2}, z \in C$ \ {2}, on the disc $|z| < 2$

I've been working at this for half an hour and haven't got anywhere. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where exactly do you have problems?

Comment: Like I said, I haven't got anywhere. I don't even know how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Notice that $$ \frac{z^2}{z-2} = z^2 \frac{1}{z-2}$$ so it's enough to calculate the Taylor-series of $\frac{1}{z-2}.$

Comment: @user66081 right... I should get some sleep!

Comment: So I calculate the series of $\frac{1}{z-2}$ and then multiply the whole series by $z^2$?

Comment: @JSimmons Yes, that is what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding in Taylor series around $z = 2$ is easy because of
$z^2 / (z - 2) = 4 + (z - 2) + 4 / (z - 2)$. To expand around $z = 0$, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+z%5E2+%2F+(z-2)+around+z%3D0). Hint: Try $1 + q + q^2 + ... = 1 / (1 - q)$ for $q = z/2$.